# Multiple fetch data axios with React Hooks - render data

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm using React hooks and axios, based on a previous example to fetch data from multiple endpoints.
I'm having troubles rendering the data, though.

I've [forked](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-cache-ripw0) a precious example where you can see the issue.
Can someone help and point out where I'm going wrong with the .map() ...?

Thank you!!

Comment: where is the .map() in the code sample?

Comment: Put a [mcve] **in the question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setGitData({ data: respGlobal.data, repos: respGlobal.data });
```

`respGlobal` was used in two places

```
{resp.data}
```

Would have not worked in JSX because it is an object and it expects a string

Full working example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import "./styles.css";

const username = "mayankshubham";
function App() {
  const [resp, setGitData] = useState({ data: null, repos: null });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const respGlobal = await axios(
        `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`
      );
      const respRepos = await axios(
        `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`
      );

      setGitData({ data: respGlobal.data, repos: respRepos.data });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log("render");
  if (resp.data) {
    console.log("d", resp.data, resp.repos);
  }

  return (
    <div>
  <h1>Hello </h1>
    <div>{JSON.stringify(resp.data)}</div>
    <br />
    <div>{JSON.stringify(resp.repos)}</div>
  </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks very much, I am fetching data from another API and it did work. I was basically trying to follow the React docs to render the list  `const { resp } = data;
 const bookList = data.map((genre, i) => <li key={genre.i} name={genre.name} />);` and then just render ` {bookList}` in the return ... & .map() was throwing error....